# Custom arguments in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, arguments

I have to write a script that will perform various tasks based on which arguments are passed from the command line. The name of the script is 'safeDel.sh'
What I have so far is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

arg=$1
r_file=$2

if [$arg == '-l']
then
#List all files in trash can
echo '$arg'

elif [$arg == '-r']
then
#recover r_file
echo '$arg'

elif [$arg == '-d']
then
#Delete (interactively?) the contents of trash directory 
echo '$arg'

elif [$arg == '-t']
then
#Display total usage in bytes of trash directory
echo '$arg'

fi
```

At this stage, I am simply trying to use the if/else statement to print out the appropriate argument. However, if i type './safeDel.sh -r', the output is:

./safeDel.sh: line 6 [-r command not found]

./safeDel.sh: line 11 [-r command not found]

./safeDel.sh: line 16 [-r command not found]

./safeDel.sh: line 21 [-r command not found]

What is the correct way to amend my code so I can have the script perform certain tasks based on passed arguments?

Comment: Add spaces after `[` and before `]`. Also double you variable `"$arg"`. Last go to [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to validate your file

Comment: Spaces fixed it, thank you @oliv

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Adding spaces around the text in the brackets [ ] fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to consider using the `bash` shell builtin `getopts` instead.  I'm assuming that `r_file` is only required with the `-r` option, that's the `:` after the `r`.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts lr:dt arg
do
    case $arg in
        i) #List all files in trash can
           echo "$arg"      # Use double quotes, not single
           ;;
        r) #recover r_file
           r_file="$OPTARG"
           echo "$arg"   
           echo "$r_file"
           ;;
        d) #Delete (interactively?) the contents of trash directory
           echo "$arg"   
           ;;
        t) #Display total usage in bytes of trash directory
           echo "$arg"   
           ;;
    esac
done
```

On the command-line (where `$` is the prompt):

```
$ ./gash.sh -r fred.txt
r
fred.txt

$ ./gash.sh -r
./gash.sh: option requires an argument -- r

$ ./gash.sh -x
./gash.sh: illegal option -- x

$ ./gash.sh -dr fred.txt
d
r
fred.txt
```